# How to show one by one alert at different Time and delay

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

i have to show different type of alerts with different time delay, Display the alerts one by one.one alert show and stay some time then next alert show with delay ....one by one showing This is my code

```
for ( int j = 0; j  < [[CMAppData appData].arrayDistanceAlert count]; j++)
{

        CMBeaconsDisplayList * displayData = [[CMAppData appData].arrayDistanceAlert objectAtIndex:j];


        if ([displayData.type isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            if ([displayData.type isEqualToString:@"1"] &&[displayData.displayForTime isEqualToString:@"0"]) {


                [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:displayData afterDelay:[displayData.displayForTime intValue]*60];
            }

            else{

                double delayInSeconds =[displayData.displayForTime intValue] *10 ;

                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                    NSLog(@"%f",delayInSeconds);

                    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayData.title message:displayData.content delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"pause", nil];
                    alert.alertViewStyle =UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
                    [alert show];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissUIAlertViewType:) withObject:alert afterDelay:15];

                });

                               }

        }

        else {

            if ([displayData.type isEqualToString:@"2"]&&[displayData.displayForTime isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayData.title message:displayData.content delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
            else{
                double delayInSeconds =[displayData.displayForTime intValue]*10;

                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                    CustomIOSAlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOSAlertView alloc] init];
                    UIView *customView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-100)];
                    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    [alertView setContainerView:customView];

                    UIScrollView  *MyScrollVw= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20 ,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-100)];
                    MyScrollVw.delegate= self;
                    [MyScrollVw setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
                    [MyScrollVw setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
                    MyScrollVw.scrollEnabled= YES;
                    MyScrollVw.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
                    MyScrollVw.contentSize= CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20 ,1150);//(width,height)
                    [customView addSubview:MyScrollVw];


                    UILabel * lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, customView.frame.size.width, 30.0)];
                    lblTitle.text = displayData.title;
                    lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
                    lblTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
                    lblTitle.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
                    lblTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                    lblTitle.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
                    lblTitle.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    [MyScrollVw addSubview:lblTitle];

                    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, lblTitle.frame.origin.y+lblTitle.frame.size.height, customView.frame.size.width, 250)];
                    displayData.image = [displayData.image stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
                    if(displayData.image && ![displayData.image isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
                    {
                    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:displayData.image] placeholderImage:nil options:/* DISABLES CODE */ (0) == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
                    }
                    if ([displayData.image length]==0)
                    {
                        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
                    }
                    [MyScrollVw addSubview:imageView];


                    NSString *videoString = displayData.video;
                    NSString *lastWord = [[videoString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] lastObject];
                    self.playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]init];
                    self.playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, imageView.frame.origin.y+imageView.frame.size.height, customView.frame.size.width, 250.0);
                    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:lastWord playerVars:@{@"playsinline":@1}];
                    [MyScrollVw addSubview:self.playerView];



                    UIButton * btnPlayAudio = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,self.playerView .frame.origin.y+self.playerView .frame.size.height, customView.frame.size.width-20, 30)];

                    [ btnPlayAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudio:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    btnPlayAudio.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                    [btnPlayAudio setTitle:@"Play Audio" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [btnPlayAudio setAccessibilityValue:displayData.audio];

                    [MyScrollVw addSubview:btnPlayAudio];

                    UILabel * lblDescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,btnPlayAudio .frame.origin.y + btnPlayAudio .frame.size.height, customView.frame.size.width-20, 100)];
                    lblDescription.text = displayData.content;
                    lblDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
                    lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
                    [lblDescription sizeToFit];
                    lblDescription.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
                    lblDescription.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                    lblDescription.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
                    lblDescription.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    lblDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    lblDescription.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    lblDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    [MyScrollVw addSubview:lblDescription];
                    [alertView show];

                    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissImageAlertView:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:15];

                });

                delayInSeconds = delayInSeconds * 10;

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Setup your code for alert creation, passing in the values you need for that specific alert, like 'createAlertWithText:@"some text"' and then focus on the delay bit - work out the logic for when you want the alert to fire, what to do if an alert is showing and so on. Keep the 'brains' and the 'display' in different methods.

Answer (score -1):

setTimeout: allows to run a function once after the interval of time.

```
alert('Before the Delay');

function afterDelay() {
    alert('After the Delay');
}

setTimeout(afterDelay, 2000);
```